# Encompass quotes around something that requires quotes to begin with?

Tags: javascript

Okay I didn't know how to word the question so let me give you an example. I'm trying to assign a values to the background position using JavaScript.  I will be using x and y values.  If I wanted to put an arbitrary figure in, it would look like.

```
document.getElementById('background-Container').style.backgroundPosition = "120px 10px";
```

My question is how do you put those " " (quotes) around the numbers if my JavaScript looks like this:

```
var x = 120;
var y = 10;
document.getElementById('background-Container').style.backgroundPosition = x + 'px' + '' + y + 'px';
```

Comment: it's not working because you don't have a space between your positions. Use `x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px'`

Comment: You don't need to. Just replace `''` with `' '`. ---------> `x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px'`.

Comment: It wouldn't work anyway, because I need the "" to emcompass the whole thing, that is what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: Why not just try it then learn why you're asking the wrong question?

Comment: Oh I guess I figured you had too, since that is the right syntax, I guess JavaScript is very forgiving

Comment: If you do that your string will look like this ----> `'"120px10px"'`, which is ofcourse not what you want.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to say with "something that requires quotes to begin with". `backgroundPosition` does not "require quotes to begin with". It requires a **string**. That could be a literal string, as in your first example, and yes, literal strings are written using quotes. Or, it could be a string **expression**, which could take many different forms, including the concatenation you are doing, but in any case does **NOT** need or want quotes around the expression (although it may well use quotes around string literals participating in the expression).